# Skip Parent Background in Child class while inherit other properties

Tags: css, angular

I don't want child class to inherit the immediate parent class background color which has background color as white. Instead it should skip and take background color from parent component which is bluebackground. When I use the transparent background in child class it should show blue color not white. Rest of the property of parent (whitebackground class) should be inherited just not the white background in child class.

I cannot do any changes on Parent component just I can do changes using css.

app component :

```
<div class="bluebackground">
<app-test>
</app-test>
</div>
```

Component: test

```
BlueBackGround Start
  <div class="whitebackground">
      Some White Background Stuff that I need
      <div class="child">
          Here i want background which should skip the parent whitebackground and show blue color same as bluebackground class <br />      
      </div>
  </div>
BlueBackGround End
```

Here is the Css

```
.child {
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: green;
    background:transparent;
  }
  .bluebackground{
    background: blue;
     font-size: 3rem;
  }

  .whitebackground {
    background:white;
  }
```

**StackBlitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hbfvjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Michael D for his inputs.

This is how I solved it

I had to move the white background color from whitebackground class to new class called newwhitebackground class.

**Html**

```
BlueBackGround Start
  <div class="whitebackground">
      <div class="newwhitebackground">
      Some White Background Stuff that I need
      </div>
      <div class="child">
          Here i want background which should skip the parent whitebackground and show blue color same as bluebackground class <br />      
      </div>
  </div>
BlueBackGround End
```

**CSS**

```
.child {
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-align: center; 
    background:transparent;
  }
    .whitebackground {
    color:yellow;
  }
 .newwhitebackground {
   background-color:white;
 }
```

**Here is the stackblitz**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pyhqwr

Answer (score 1):

You could try to change the CSS to the following

```css
.child {
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-align: center; 
}

.bluebackground {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.whitebackground {
  background:white;
  color:yellow;
}

.bluebackground, .child {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2kk6r1)

#### Update

There is a dirty way to include the CSS selectors from the app component to the child component.

test.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css', '../app.component.css']   // <-- include `app.component.css` here
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Now you could use the `bluebackground` selector in the test component.

test.component.html

```html
BlueBackGround Start
  <div class="whitebackground">
      Some White Background Stuff that I need
      <div class="child bluebackground">     <!-- include `bluebackground` here -->
          Here i want background which should skip the parent whitebackground and show blue color same as bluebackground class <br />      
      </div>
  </div>
BlueBackGround End
```

I've modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-i16hch)

#### Update: `encapsulation`

You could set the `encapsulation` to `ViewEncapsulation.None` in the app.component and rename the `child` selector to `bluebackground` in the child as well. Try the following

app.component.ts

```js
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None     // <-- set `ViewEncapsulation.None` here
})
export class AppComponent  {
  ...
}
```

test.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

test.component.css

```css
/* overwrite/introduce values to the `bluebackground` specific to test component */ 
.bluebackground {
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-align: center; 
}

.whitebackground {
  background:white;
  color:yellow;
}
```

test.component.html

```html
BlueBackGround Start
  <div class="whitebackground">
      Some White Background Stuff that I need
      <div class="bluebackground"> 
          Here i want background which should skip the parent whitebackground and show blue color same as bluebackground class <br />      
      </div>
  </div>
BlueBackGround End
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ir1stz)

Comment: kindly see the stackblitz again. i updated it the bluebackground in different component

Comment: I've updated the answer, please see if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer again. The problem in my case is the parent component is changing and the child component has to adopt the background of the parent component. I was expecting child component to skip the parent component background by using some operator. May be something like NOT operator.

Comment: I've updated the answer to use `Encapsulation.none`. But I don't think there is a pure CSS solution for your requirement. You might be able to do it using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<div class="bluebackground">
  Blue Background Start
  <div class="whitebackground">
      Some White Background Stuff that I need
      <div class="child bluebackground">
          Here i want background which should skip the parent whitebackground and show blue color same as mainbackground class <br />      
      </div>
  </div>
  Blue Background End
<div>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-offmbw?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: Thanks for that Adrita,